# Why just write a field and not doing anything with it?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm reading the source of mongoose, find such code in https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/collection.js#L23:

```
/**
 * The collection name
 *
 * @api public
 */

Collection.prototype.name;
```

I don't understand why this line exist. Does it here just for generating document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

It helps anyone reading the code know that this property is meant to be accessed publicly, and helps the doc generator signal the same.